Why can probabilities or weights be used in calculating Expected Utility?
We know by definition that the Expected Utility of Wealth is the probability weighted average of the utilities of each wealth outcome. (Which is just the definition of the expected value applied to a function U)
This can be written as:
$$E[U(W)]=\sum_{1}^{N}p_{i}U(w_{i})$$
But it seems in portfolio optimisation and questions related to it, we focus on the allocation of weights of the assets, rather than probabilities of the returns. It would make sense in the fact that each return would have a 1/n probability weight, and thus the average would just be /n.
For e.g.  if we had 2 risky assets with a mean rate of return of 3% and mean rate of return of 6%, and we want to find proportions such that E(U) is maximised,
then the first step would be,
$$E_{p}=0.03w_{1}+0.06(1-w_{1})$$
Here probability is not even involved in the expression. Is an assumption of probability even present? In other cases/questions particularly covered in Utility Theory Week 2, expected value is determined with probabilities assigned to the rates of return of an asset and its effect on wealth.
And referring to the same example above, say the utility function of the investor is $$U(W)=W-0.25W^{2}$$
We can take the Expectation of the function , thus giving us
$$E[U(W)] = E(W) -0.25 * E(W^2)$$
Where E(W) = Ep = 0.06 - 0.03w1
This approach of applying the Expectation directly to the function should be analogous as the above probability weighted average definition, I am sure it is I just don't see why. All these approaches are fundamentally dealing with uncertainty in some measure.
Why can probabilities or weights be used in calculating Expected Utility?
Sorry for the long (and probably basic) question.
Thank you in advance

Expected utility (E [U (W)] ) is indeed a probability weighted average of utility, but in portfolio optimization, more attention is paid to the weight allocation of assets rather than explicitly dealing with the probability of return.
The allocation of weights reflects the response to risks and implies the probability distribution of returns. By adjusting asset weights, investors can optimize expected utility without directly dealing with the probability of each asset.
Then, the utility function  (U (W)=W -0.25W ^ 2 ), applied in portfolio optimization, can be directly calculated using (E [U (W)]=E (W) -0.25 E (W ^ 2) ).

"...implies the probability distribution of returns." Sorry I am slightly confused what this means, can you show this mathematically? I understand it reflects risk, but how does the allocation of weights imply the probability distribution of returns?

Ah I think I get it. E(W) already takes into account the probability distribution as expected value is probability weighted average.
$$E(W)=\sum_{}^{}w_{i}p(w_{i})$$
So the probabilities are implied. And also in the case of a quadratic utility function the expectation is a linear operator and thus expected utility can be written as just a function of E(W) and Var(W).
Is this correct?
